# How do I stop user from running a report if boolean parameter value is false/No?

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

How do I prevent user from running a report if boolean parameter value is false/No?

Or,

How do I disable the View Report button if boolean parameter value is false/No?

Scenario:

I am creating a new report say "Report 2" that works off data created by another report say "Report 1" run prior. As a check to remind the user to run Report 1, I have added a boolean parameter on Report 2 - "Have you executed Report 1?" that is  dropdown list of Yes and No options with a default set to No.

I want to force the user to select Yes before executing the report, else display a message or just not load the report or keep View Report button disabled (thats not important, any option would do).

Can someone please give me some direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this....

**Option 1:** You could have a simple text parameter as you described, with two available options and the default as "No". You could then use that parameter in your dataset something like

```
IF @ConfirmParameter = "Yes"
    BEGIN
       SELECT * FROM MyTable -- Original query here
    END
```

This would return no data to your dataset unless the drop down was set to Yes. You could then set the NoRowsMessage property in your reports tablix/table to "You need to run Report 1 first" for whatever you want.

**Option 2:** You could have a simple boolean parameter with no default. This would prevent the report from running until at least one option is taken, you could then something similar implement option 1 if the user still ran the report.

**Option 3:**  Have a drop down with just a Yes option in but with no default.

**Option 4:** This final option may not be suitable depending on your scenario but if Report 1 always has to be run immediately before Report 2 then you could add a link (text box with "Go to Report" action) in Report 1 to run Report 2. This would only be visible once Report 1 has been run. Then change Report 2 to be hidden from the SSRS Web Portal/Report Manager so Report 2 cannot be easily run on its own.

Comment: Thanks @Alan I will try that.

Comment: Hey @Alan, unforunately option 1 does not work. Does not like the parameter.

Comment: Where does it not work? Did you set the parameter type to Text?

Comment: if I use if @PriceBookReportYN = "Yes" BEGIN --- END it prompts me with a Define Query Parameters window. Note this parameter above is not same as Report paramters. This is a query parameter.

Comment: The report parameter has to be the exact same name as the query parameter otherwise if will not be passed to the query. So in the dataset query DON'T declare the parameter, just use it as you described above, then SSRS will add a report parameter if a matching report parameter name cannot be found.

Comment: I got it working. The problem was double quotes. AS soon as I changed them to single quotes 'Yes', it started working. I have updated your answer. Thanks for that.

Comment: Sorry about that, I posted that from phone and didn't notice. Glad you got it sorted.